# hdbscan error when inside rapids container

Tags: cupy, rapids, cudf, hdbscan

I am using rapids UMAP in conjunction with HDBSCAN inside a rapidsai docker container : `rapidsai/rapidsai-core:0.18-cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.7`

```
import cudf
import cupy
from cuml.manifold import UMAP
import hdbscan 
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from cuml.experimental.preprocessing import StandardScaler

blobs, labels = make_blobs(n_samples=100000, n_features=10)
df_gpu=cudf.DataFrame(blobs)

scaler= StandardScaler()
cupy_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(df_gpu.values)


projector= UMAP(n_components=3, n_neighbors=2000)
cupy_projected=projector.fit_transform(cupy_scaled)


numpy_projected=cupy.asnumpy(cupy_projected)
clusterer= hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=1000, prediction_data=True, gen_min_span_tree=True)#, core_dist_n_jobs=1) 
clusterer.fit(numpy_projected)
```

I get an error which is fixed if I use `core_dist_n_jobs=1` but makes the code slower:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TerminatedWorkerError                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 clusterer= hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=1000, prediction_data=True, gen_min_span_tree=True)
> ----> 2 clusterer.fit(numpy_projected)
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py
> in fit(self, X, y)
> 917          self._condensed_tree,
> 918          self._single_linkage_tree,
> --> 919          self._min_spanning_tree) = hdbscan(X, **kwargs)
> 920
> 921         if self.prediction_data:
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py
> in hdbscan(X, min_cluster_size, min_samples, alpha,
> cluster_selection_epsilon, metric, p, leaf_size, algorithm, memory,
> approx_min_span_tree, gen_min_span_tree, core_dist_n_jobs,
> cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster,
> match_reference_implementation, **kwargs)
> 613                                              approx_min_span_tree,
> 614                                              gen_min_span_tree,
> --> 615                                              core_dist_n_jobs, **kwargs)
> 616         else:  # Metric is a valid BallTree metric
> 617             # TO DO: Need heuristic to decide when to go to boruvka;
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in
> **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 350
> 351     def **call**(self, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 352         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
> 353
> 354     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py
> in _hdbscan_boruvka_kdtree(X, min_samples, alpha, metric, p,
> leaf_size, approx_min_span_tree, gen_min_span_tree, core_dist_n_jobs,
> **kwargs)
> 276                                  leaf_size=leaf_size // 3,
> 277                                  approx_min_span_tree=approx_min_span_tree,
> --> 278                                  n_jobs=core_dist_n_jobs, **kwargs)
> 279     min_spanning_tree = alg.spanning_tree()
> 280     # Sort edges of the min_spanning_tree by weight
>
> hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx in
> hdbscan._hdbscan_boruvka.KDTreeBoruvkaAlgorithm.**init**()
>
> hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx in
> hdbscan._hdbscan_boruvka.KDTreeBoruvkaAlgorithm._compute_bounds()
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py
> in **call**(self, iterable)    1052     1053             with
> self._backend.retrieval_context():
> -> 1054                 self.retrieve()    1055             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done    1056
> elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py
> in retrieve(self)
> 931             try:
> 932                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
> --> 933                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
> 934                 else:
> 935                     self._output.extend(job.get())
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py
> in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
> 540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
> 541         try:
> --> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
> 543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
> 544             raise TimeoutError from e
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in
> result(self, timeout)
> 433                 raise CancelledError()
> 434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
> --> 435                 return self.__get_result()
> 436             else:
> 437                 raise TimeoutError()
>
> /opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py in
> __get_result(self)
> 382     def __get_result(self):
> 383         if self._exception:
> --> 384             raise self._exception
> 385         else:
> 386             return self._result
>
> TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was
> unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault
> while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the
> Operating System to kill the worker.
>
> The exit codes of the workers are {EXIT(1)}

Is there a way to solve this issue but still keep HDBSCAN to be fast?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `min_samples` to a value

In https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/345#issuecomment-628749332 , lmcinnes says that you "may have issues if your `min_cluster_size` is large and your `min_samples` is not set. You could try setting `min_samples` to something smallish and see if that helps."  I noticed that you do not have a `min_samples` set in your code.

Comment: Actually I had it set to 700, but left it out as I thought is not relevant, but I guess 700 is not exactly smallish

Comment: actually tried setting the values down from 700 until 10 but the error persisted

Comment: Hmmm.... My suggestion is to create an issue on that github repo.  The devs should get back to you, esp with this minimum reproducible.  You can also create a feature request on the RAPIDS cuML repo for HDBSCAN, so you can do the entire workflow on GPU.  The RAPIDS devs are really responsive and helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I had asked for hdbscan on rapids, got a response that it's in progress, but I wanted to use the CPU version in the meantime